# How to apply PCA on a dataset and print the relevant features

Tags: python-3.x, pca

I have a dataset with 23 rows and 48 columns. I am applying PCA to reduce the number of column dimensions. I use the following codes examples and I see that only 23 are required features:

```
#first
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA().fit(only_features)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')

#second
df_pca = pca.fit_transform(X=only_features)
df_pca = pd.DataFrame(df_pca)
print(df_pca.shape)
```

However, I would want to know which are the features required. Like for example: If the original dataset had columns A-z and reduced by PCA, then I would want to know which are the features selected.

How to do that?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to this [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001942/10452700) & [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62553642/10452700), Sklearn's documentation states that the number of components retained when you don't specify the `n_components` parameter is `min(n_samples, n_features)`. So `min(23, 48) = 23` that's why you required 23 in your case.

**Solution 1:** if you use `Sklearn` library credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845697/10452700)

- check variance of PCs by: `pca.explained_variance_ratio_`
- check importance of PCs by: `print(abs( pca.components_ ))`
- using customized function to extract more info about PCs see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62145186/10452700).

**Solution 2:** if you use `PCA` library [documenetation](https://pypi.org/project/pca/)

```py
# Initialize
model = pca()
# Fit transform
out = model.fit_transform(X)

# Print the top features. The results show that f1 is best, followed by f2 etc
print(out['topfeat'])

#     PC      feature
# 0  PC1      f1
# 1  PC2      f2
# 2  PC3      f3
# 3  PC4      f4
# 4  PC5      f5
...
```

Even you can make a plot of PCs by:  `model.plot()`

[image: img]